# How do I find the longest words in a string?

Tags: java, string

I want to find the *longest words* in a given `String`.

The following code checks for the *longest word*, but I want *every other* word with the *same length* as well.

```
try (BufferedReader fileInputReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath))){
    String line = fileInputReader.readLine();

    line = line.replaceAll("[^äÄöÖüÜßa-zA-Z ]", "");
    String[] sentence = line.split(" ");
    String longestWord = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
        if (sentence[i].length() > longestWord.length()) {
            longestWord = sentence[i];
        }
    }

    System.out.println(longestWord);
}
```

Comment: Why do you replace all the German special characters by an empty `String`? Doesn't that change the length of certain words?

Comment: Just add the longest words to a list, then when you encounter a longer word, clear the list and put that word in .

Comment: @deHaar the code replaces everything other than the mentioned characters with a space.

Comment: @f1sh OK, thanks... haven't seen that. It still changes the word lengths, doesn't it?

Comment: @deHaar yes, it does. For some reason that "cleanup" was necessary enough to write that line of code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Then you have to use a *collection* of these `longestWords`, e.g.

```
  ArrayList<String> longestWords = new ArrayList<String>();
  int longestWordLength = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
      if (sentence[i].length() > longestWordLength) { // longer
          longestWordLength = sentence[i].length();
          longestWords.clear();
          longestWords.add(sentence[i]);       
      } 
      else if (sentence[i].length() == longestWordLength) { // same length
          longestWords.add(sentence[i]);       
      }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < longestWords.size(); ++i) 
      System.out.println(longestWords.get(i));
```

Comment: I think you are missing a semicolon in the if code block. Can't edit since that change is obviously below 6 characters. Apart from that, your code works perfectly.

Comment: @HeartCore: thank you, for sure `;` is required after the `.length()`

Answer (score 0):

```
try(BufferedReader fileInputReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath))){
    String line = fileInputReader.readLine();
    line = line.replaceAll("[^äÄöÖüÜßa-zA-Z ]", "");
    String[] sentence = line.split(" ");
    ArrayList<String> longestWord = new ArrayList<>();
    int maxLength = 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++){
      if(sentence[i].length() > maxLength){
        longestword.clear(); 
        longestWord.add(sentence[i]);
        maxLength=sentece[i].length();
      }
    else if(sentence[i].length() == maxLength)
     {
       longestWord.add(sentence[i]);
     }
   }
  System.out.println(longestWord);
  }
```